# jquery .click when removing class

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/smotru/fqDZt/
when i click on any divs it should not alert me because there is no class..
what should i do to make it work correctly ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.selpage1').click(function () {
        selpage(1);
    });
    $('.selpage2').click(function () {
        selpage(2);
    });
    $('.selpage3').click(function () {
        selpage(3);
    });
    for (j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
        $('#pg' + j).removeClass('selpage' + j);
    }
});

function selpage(i) {
    alert(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wheren you remove class you should also unbind click event

```
$('.selpage' + j).unbind('click');
```

Comment: In that case, do not unbind but in the click event look for the present of a class to make a decision.